# Flutter webView on Windows response

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I am creating webView on windows using this package: "https://pub.dev/packages/webview_windows/example" sadly I can not find solution for "listening" for response.

On mobile I created working solution:

```dart
WebView(                    
                    (...)
                    navigationDelegate: (action) {
                      if (action.url.contains(callbackUrlPart)) {
                        cartBloc.add(GoToFinish());
                        widget.goNext.call();
                        return NavigationDecision.navigate;
                      } else {
                        cartBloc.add(GoToFinish());
                        widget.goNext.call();
                        return NavigationDecision.navigate;
                      }
                    },
                  )
```

It takes specific action after user on my webView clics specific button, and application moves on.

I can not find similar solution for windows web view, how to listen what user clics there or web page sends me specific data, righ now it shows "true"?[image]